# Cannot update the timestamp column in mysql using golang

Tags: mysql, go, orm, beego

I am using golang in my application.I m using beego framework to create it.I use beego ORM to do the database operations.I do the following

```
 num, err := o.Raw("UPDATE apply_leave SET leavestatus=?,resultdate=?
 WHERE leaveid=?",leaveResult.LeaveResult, time.Now(),leave_id).Exec()
```

When i run this i m getting the following error

```
"Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '15:46:59' for column 'resultdate' at row 1"
```

Please do note that the resultdate is of type timestamp.Appreciate any help...

Comment: can you check ad accept the answer if it satisfies the requirement

Answer (score 1):

You may format it as format time as  `"2006-01-02 15:04:05"` explicitly

Changing your code as follows will help

```
const MySQLTimeFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
num, err := o.Raw("UPDATE apply_leave SET leavestatus=?,resultdate=?
 WHERE leaveid=?",leaveResult.LeaveResult, time.Now().Format(MySQLTimeFormat),leave_id).Exec()
```